# what should i be doing for seo as a programmer?

Tags: seo, php, web-development, search-engines, website-promotion

I'm working on a niche classifieds/listings type site. What should i be doing to make each page on the site to be uniquely indexable by search engines.

As per my understanding, basically i need to generate the title, meta-tags etc. dynamically or programatically.

Perhaps do some url rewriting? What type of url rewriting works best?

The site has categories and cities , so perhaps they should be included in url's, titles. meta-tags etc.?

What else is missing, what are the other stuff i should be working on?

Comment: Well why not use WordPress SEO plugin by Yoast as an example of how to handle the meta tags for each page, and what options to give your users in the applications.

Then you can also use their database schema to create your categories and cities.

What else is missing? That would be a long list. I'm suggesting this be closed there's no real answer to your question

Comment: Long list doesn't mean a vague question...  This one is fairly basic... there are some best practices out there for this kind of stuff.. i' waiting to hear about them from the experts... may be not all of them but at least the major ones... BTW, i don't use Wordpress but i'll have a look at Yoast, it might be helpful.

Comment: This question, in its present form, does not meet our [quality guidelines](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) - please consider posting discrete questions on their own instead of listing multiple questions.

Comment: Take a look at '[What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)' this should give you the basics

Answer (score 1):

> What should i be doing to make each page on the site to be uniquely
>   indexable by search engines.

Create individual unique pages create an XML sitemap submit to Google and Bing. Be sure your robots.txt isn't blocking access or that you've used `noindex` or `nofollow` meta tags

You can manually add your meta tags it really doesn't matter how you create them so long as you have at the very least a `title` meta tag.

> What type of url rewriting works best?

It doesn't matter how you re-write URL's the search engines can care less how they got that way. So re-write them however you want.

You don't have to include the categories or cities in the URL as much as the Title of the page, the content of the page. And incoming links will help more so with ranking your NYC page since you'll be competing with thousands of pages content wise you wont be able to compete IMHO, you'll need links lots of them to out rank say craigslist.

Answer (score 1):

- Clean up URLs; try to remove '?' and '&', for instance, from the address of any page you want crawled.
- Make sure that the words in the URL, the `<title>` tag, and `<h*>` all make sense and are related to each other and the page content.
- Don't put anything in javascript that you want crawled.
- Get signed up, and the site set up, for Google Analytics and Google's webmaster tools, including submitting a sitemap.
- Basically set up a good web site, one that's clean, simple, and easy to use.  A good exercise is to look at your site using a non-graphical browser like 'links' or 'lynx'.  What you see there is what a crawler will see.
- Watch your logs, both access and error, for clues as to what else you need to do.  This will require using 'sort', 'uniq', 'awk', and their friends, so get familiar with them.  (This is assuming you're on a Unix or Linux machine -- if you're on Windows, then cygwin will give you those.)